# Get last run time for a task configured in web.config

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sitecore, task

For a task configured in web.config, is there a way to figure out the last time this task was run? It's easy to figure that out from tasks that are configured in Sitecore tasks where a field holds this information. I tried to find something in the Sitecore API but wasn't successful.

Comment: hello, check this blog post..reference Scheduled Tasks section. It looks to me that you could simply log your task after it's scheduled and ran. http://sitecorejohn.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/all-about-sitecore-scheduling-agents-and-tasks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are INFO entries in the Sitecore logs that tells you when jobs are run. The log folder can be located inside of your data folder, which can be located in `web.config` on the key `dataFolder`

Comment: I tried this approach based on the first responder's comment. But I could never get it to work. Sitecore documentation isn't the most helpful. Could you provide me with a starting point about what class or function to use to get the current log. I can take it from there.

Comment: Programmatically reading from the Sitecore log: http://theclientview.net/2011/02/log-parser-lizard-gui/

Comment: You're looking for: `INFO Job started: Namespace.MyTasks.Task`

Comment: Also, please note that the log file is flushed with an interval, so programmatically looking for a task run from the log files is not reliant in terms of time. Of that is what you need, you should instead log the task's activity into a Sitecore item.